# group by inside group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

let's say I have emp_no, year_that_got_paid, gender, amount_paid
I want to group by year_that_got_paid and gender, so that I can see per year (1990, 1991...) how many ppl of each gender got paid. However, if the same emp_no appears twice in the same year, it counts it as one more person with that gender, but it's actually the same.

Notes: I simplified the table for the question but it actually has more columns and primary key doesn't help to prevent the duplicate employee IDs for that year.

Therefore, I thought, maybe a kind of

```
select count(*) 
from tableX 
group by year_that_got_paid, gender
```

but then I would need a second group by or some kind of "distinct" to count only once every emp_no, year_that_got_paid. If I group by the 3 fields it doesn't work either as it would greate a lot of rows saying 1, 2 or whatever amount of times the employee received salary that year.

Comment: Sample data and expected result.

Comment: You yourself suggested DISTINCT, so why doesn't that work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table stores money people earned. The people can switch genders, so you store the gender along. And they can earn multiple amounts in a year.

So, if Bobby (Roberta / Robert) earned 1000$ as a woman, 500$ as a man, and 500$ as a woman again in 2020, you want this to count as 1 man in 2020 (having earned 500$) and one woman (having earned 1500$).

In order to achieve this, aggregate by employee number and gender in a year first:

```
select
  year_that_got_paid,
  count(case when gender = 'male' then 1 end) as male_count,
  count(case when gender = 'female' then 1 end) as female_count,
  sum(case when gender = 'male' then sum_amount_paid else 0 end) as male_paid,
  sum(case when gender = 'female' then sum_amount_paid else 0 end) as female_paid
from
(
  select year_that_got_paid, emp_id, gender, sum(amount_paid) as sum_amount_paid
  from transgender_payments
  group by year_that_got_paid, emp_id, gender
) per_emp_and_their_gender
group by year_that_got_paid
order by year_that_got_paid;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do a COUNT DISTINCT on the employee id